# Ninject conventions generic interface having different number of arguments than concrete class

Tags: ninject, conventions, arity

Is there a way, using NInject conventions, to bind a generic interface that has a different number of type parameters than the concrete class that implements it?

For example:

```
    public interface IRepository<T1, T2>
    {
        ...
    }
    public class Repository<T1, T2, T3> : IRepository<T1, T2>
    {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: And how should Ninject guess that `T3` argument when the resolver only supplies `T1`, and `T2`. How would you do this by hand?

Comment: Bind(typeof(IRepository<C1,C2>)).To(typeof(Repository<C1,C2,C3>));

Comment: Try to do this: `To (typeof (Repository <,, C3>))`. This will unfortunately nor compile.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can do this directly, but the solution is rather simple: create a new type with two type arguments that inherits from `Repository<T1, T2, T3>`, like this:

```cs
class Rep<T1, T2> : Repository<T1, T2, ActualType>
{
}
```

This type can be mapped directly to a `IRepository<T1, T2>` without leaving any unresolved generic type arguments behind.

Comment: That sort of defeats the purpose of having the generics in the first place; T3 is different for each distinct combination of T1, T2.

Comment: If T3 differs, there is no way Ninject can guess that type for you. You will have to call Bind.To for every T1-T2 combination that needs to be resolved.

Comment: That's what I thought.  I thought maybe I could do a custom binding (IBindingGenerator) and handle it there...

Comment: Just out of interest, what would the logic be in your case to select to correct `ActualType`?

Comment: Basically I have a Caching layer that is different from my data layer.  So I would have something like IRepository<key, ObjectCache> that would use Repository<key, Object, ObjectCache>.  This way I can have one implementation that uses EF to get the data, and one that uses XML files.  Each will use the same interface for the business logic but have a different implementation.
So in each case there will only be one class that implements IRepository but the generic signature will not match.